# Loading images on a page with php call in folder

Tags: php, html

here is the code my website uses to call pictures, it calls about 100 pictures and they dont load all at once, you need to sit on the page for about 5 mins for them all to load. I was told this might be the http buffer size or something? Anyway, no-one is willing to wait that long for pics to load, so what can i do (other than make a new page for each section of 50 pics or so) to either make them all load fast, or to make like spoiler tags where only the one you open loads, but then loads faster. I've thought of using the Javascript onload event, but not sure how i'd implement it here.

POI: this page may end up with 200 maybe even up to 500 pics on, theyre downsized to 5mp from 24mp so they upload faster, but don't download so people can see them very fast.

Thanks in advance

```
<?php
  $dirname = "pictures/photos/Folder1/";
  $images = scandir($dirname);
  $ignore = Array(".", "..");
  foreach($images as $curimg){
    if(!in_array($curimg, $ignore)) {
      echo "<a href=".$dirname.$curimg.">
      <img style='border:4px ridge #9D552D; width:125px; margin: 10px;' src='./pictures/photos/Folder1/$curimg'/></a>";
    }
  }
```

Comment: How big are the file sizes? As the width is only 125px in your styles you can think of creating thumbnails for the list view. You don't need a 5 megapixel image when it's only this wide. Also consider, if an image is like 3MB big, 50 of them are already 150MB to download.

Comment: Golly, a page that loads 500MB of images. :eeeeek: Perhaps having as much as 2,500 MB of images on it? Nooooooooooooooooo! You can use AJAX to get filenames from the server as they're required, or you can return the list of filenames as a JSON text and then allow the client to determine when an image is scrolled into view, and when this happens assign the relevant filename from the JSON as the src of the image. You may benefit from looking into "Lazy Loading".

Comment: I've thought about using every image in thumbnail then in massive, but with this number of images, it's not possible to manually make a link for each one. And sorry enhzflep i don't understand what you mean with AJAX? i've not used it before?

Comment: You can use GD or imageMagick to automatically create thumbnails from the images, simply appending `Thumb` or some other text to the filename before the extension. As for AJAX - it basically allows you to request (or send) more data to the server without refreshing the page. This could be used to ask for the filename of image number X from the server when an image without a src is scrolled into view.But it would be easier not to worry about using AJAX. You could just create a JS array of filenames using PHP and output that array into a script tag.

Comment: would this mean changing every file name though? i need something which finds the pics in the directory, and then displays them on the page, without any additional code for more pics etc, basically, i want to be able to dump pics in a folder, and then they appear on the site asap by themselves? and i need to do this for multiple folders too

Answer (score 0):

If you're not an expert in Programming, then using this jquery plugin might be of interest for you: 
http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload

when used correctly, it will ensure that the browser only loads images that are currently visible on the screen. pictures below the fold will not be loaded as long as you don't scroll down.

If you have very many images, such an approach might be the most desirable anyways as the page loads faster and quite many people will never scroll down too far.

If you're a bit experienced with programming, then dynamically generating thumbnails (e.g. with GD lib - coming with PHP by default - or ImageMagick) will not be such a hard task. Keep in mind though, that still people will need to download all these thumbnails - therefore the ideal approach might be a combination of lazy loading and thumbnail generation.

Comment: Lets say i wanted to do this then with the PHP way you mentioned if i had three images in /photos/folder called img1 img2 and img3 how would i get the php to dynamically generate the thumbnails? and then use lazy load?

Comment: in your above code, the images src would be something like src="resize.php?file=./pictures/photos/Folder1/$curimg". Then resize.php could look like the example code from here: http://php.net/manual/de/function.imagecopyresized.php

for the jquery lazyload - on that homepage, the first 4-5 paragraphs describe all that's needed to use lazyload on your site.

Comment: Sorry, now i have this, but i don't know what to change to make it work, this is my resize.php file

http://pastebin.com/q2paSy3Q

Comment: and is this correct to be in the original html file

<img src="resize.php?file=./pictures/photos/BITA2015/$curimg"/>

Comment: Right, if i get the dynamically generating images to work on the fly, how will this help loading times though? surely its the same as the html code im using at the minute, it'll still have to load all the files in full size first?

Comment: the loading times come from the amount of data that is transferred between your browser and the server. if you resize the images on the server side, they will be smaller in size. e.g. if you have a 10 Megapixel JPEG image it will usually be around 2mb. if you resize it to 320x200 pixels, it will be less than 100k. also you could store those generated thumbs on the server side, so that you don't need to do the resizing the next time.

Comment: Here's what I have at the minute: http://pastebin.com/mUJdWBAg

It doesnt throw errors, but doesnt actually load any pics, it just shows the squares for them, i think i'm using this correctly, so it must be what to put in the resize.php file, i dont think i know what to put in there? ca you help with that please/